# Custom approach in UI-management

Tags: android, user-interface

I am currently developping a prototype of an application and I am experimenting with different approaches.

I never really liked the "one `Activity` - one user interface" approach. Since I haven't got deep yet into `Fragment`s, I tried a different approach which until now is working, but shows some leaks even visible for me (not to mention for someone adepter than me).

Basically, my `main_menu.xml` looks like this

```
<!-- The main content view -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/overall_content_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    > 

    <!-- THE PROGRAM CONTENT -->
    <my.package.path.BoxProgram
        android:id="@+id/menu_box_program"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <!-- THE CLUB CONTENT -->
    <my.package.path.custom.BoxClub
        android:id="@+id/menu_box_club"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <!-- (...) -->

</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@color/greyD"
    />
```

As you see, there are several (more than the two above) custom `LinearLayout`s in this main xml file. Now from code, whenever a user selects an item of the navigation drawer, I loop throug an array containing the ids of each 'menu part', setting the visibility of each one to `View.GONE` except the one selected.

The excpected result is almost as expected: I have a single `Activity` handling the whole application, but the design is distributed onto multiple xml files and therefor neatly arranged. The only negativ part is that the whole Java code is in one file, blowing it up.

Is this a good practice? Can I claim to provide a `Fragment` like UI, which is compatible with older Android versions (before 3.0)?

Now as I tried to implement a menu part in which several `ImageView`s are arranged in a `ScrollView`, the application crashed with the `java.lang.outOfMemoryError`, which, as I searched the internet for some inputs, is caused by using mutliple Bitmaps (although I do not exactly understand why, since my images are stored as jpg and don't exceed the size of 100KB each).

Now as a first subquestion, is the problem with the `ImageView`s due to the fact that the whole application is filled in one `Activity` (and therefore the whole data is always loaded together), or is this not part of this subject (I already read [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html))?

Comment: You should try to use `Fragment`s - this is what they are for. Using the Android Support Library (https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) will allow you to use fragments while supporting devices older than 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I wouldn't say it's a good practice.
For maintainability (readability) and reusability, for instance...
Yes, you can use fragments prior to Android 3.0, thanks to the compatibility (support) library.

Take in account that **the support library DOES NOT suppport Preferences**...
For this you'll need either to go for the old good PreferenceActivity (still works well, despite deprecation) or branch your code for preferences, using a PreferenceActivity for older devices and a preferenceFragment for newer ones.

It depends on how many bitmaps are in memory at the same time.
I think you could read them one by one (or 2/3 at once) from disk, instead.
Half and half, let me guess... a lot of images and a BIG monolithic app can be expensive.